# Finding value of a parameter using set of data

Tags: python, data-analysis, curve-fitting

I have a set of value for x and y and I'm looking to find a way to find the value of a parameter for a function.

I have a function **y = Ax^{4/3}**.
I was thinking about using curvefit, but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

I tried to linearize the function and find the slope with polyfit, but the slope change radically if I remove some points.

Edit: I tried curvefit and something strange is happening. curvefit gives me A=0.55, but this value doesn't fit at all. However, 0.055 seems to work.
Here's my code.

```
def func(A,x):
  return A*x**(4/3)
popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,x[:18], y[:18])
```

Any help will be appraciated.

Comment: Can you share your `x` and `y` values, please? Thanks.

Comment: @blunova I tried different set of value for x and y and the value for the parameter is wrong no matter the values for x and y. Thus, either I'm not using curvefit the right way or I can't find the value of a parameter using curvefit. Atleast for a non linear function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to fit data to your model:

Import relevant libraries:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
```

Define `x` values:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 10)
```

Define a function representing your model:

```py
def f(x: np.ndarray, a: float) -> float:
    return a * x ** (4/3)
```

Let's sample data from the above model and add noise:

```py
y = f(x, a=16) * np.random.uniform(1, 2, len(x))
```

Perform the curve fitting:

```py
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y)
```

Plot the results:

```py
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, f(x, *popt), c="r")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My error was the order of the parameters in the function definition.
func(x,a) works, but func(a,x) gives me weird value for a. I'm not sure why.

Comment: If you take a look at the `curve_fit` documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), **parameters** section, the `f` parameter must be a callable, i.e. a function, having the form `f(x, ...)`, so the first argument of `f` must the independent variable and the other ones are the function parameters `a`, `b`, etc, while you providing the parameter as the first argument, i.e. as the independent variable, so you get weird values.